# How can I force the compiler to make critical variables in a register?

Tags: c++, optimization, visual-c++, intrinsics, avx

My self-set task was to experiment with optimising the ReLu activation function (for neural networks) where the function would activate an entire layer at a time, and rely on SIMD vectorisation and loop unrolling to get the job done much faster - with success! I've seen a consistent 4x performance increase from the standard c++ way of doing this task (that I could think of anyway.)

I'm still curious about pushing it faster and faster - and I've been looking at the disassembly of the program in Release mode, x64, msvc compiler, with all the optimisations and instruction sets on the highest setting - so in theory the compiler should be storing commonly used variables in the registers, however it refuses to do so - they're always in memory. This seems to me as highly inefficient, and one final bottleneck. I've been using intrinsics (because no inline assembly in x64 - if that was allowed, I could bypass this infuriating compiler issue entirely), and here is the code:

The global bitmask is just the MSB of a 64-bit value set to 1, and all else as zero - it's a mask 
to check if a value is negative - the ReLu is max(in, 0.0) - but I found that to be far slower, so
I've been creating a mask, that is set to true when the value is non-negative (andNOT is my 
instruction) and then using a maskload, which zeros the destination out if the mask isn't true for 
that element. Likewise, I have the global ones and zeros vectors as pre-stored values, that I would hope would be stored in registers, as they are used often and would be more efficiently placed in the ymm registers, but instead are being put on the stack.

I have experimented with creating the bitmasks, and one vectors as local const variables, in the hope that that would force them into registers, but there is no effect - they are put in a register for the first instruction, and then sent out to memory immediately afterwards.

The two loops for the activation and the derivative are separated, as they use different intrinsics - I've found that the max intrinsic is far faster than a maskload - but I can't see any other way to compute the derivative (1.0 if in > 0.0, else 0.0) with a faster intrinsic. I've tested it - counter-intuitively, the separation of the loops makes it far faster.

```cpp
void ReluTesters::reluCompBothV3(double* in, double* out, int args) {
    int unrolled = args / 16;

    __m256d* inPtr = (__m256d*) in;
    __m256d* inPtr1 = (__m256d*) in + 1;
    __m256d* inPtr2 = (__m256d*) in + 2;
    __m256d* inPtr3 = (__m256d*) in + 3;

    __m256d* actOutPtr = (__m256d*) out;
    __m256d* actOutPtr1 = (__m256d*) out + 1;
    __m256d* actOutPtr2 = (__m256d*) out + 2;
    __m256d* actOutPtr3 = (__m256d*) out + 3;

    __m256d* delOutPtr = (__m256d*)  (out + args);
    __m256d* delOutPtr1 = (__m256d*) (out + args + 4);
    __m256d* delOutPtr2 = (__m256d*) (out + args + 8);
    __m256d* delOutPtr3 = (__m256d*) (out + args + 12);

    const __m256d zeros = reluGlobalZeroVectorAVX;

    for (int i = 0; i < unrolled; ++i) {
        *actOutPtr = _mm256_max_pd(*inPtr, zeros);
        *actOutPtr1 = _mm256_max_pd(*inPtr1, zeros);
        *actOutPtr2 = _mm256_max_pd(*inPtr2, zeros);
        *actOutPtr3 = _mm256_max_pd(*inPtr3, zeros);

        inPtr += 4;
        inPtr1 += 4;
        inPtr2 += 4;
        inPtr3 += 4;

        actOutPtr += 4;
        actOutPtr1 += 4;
        actOutPtr2 += 4;
        actOutPtr3 += 4;
    }

    inPtr = (__m256d*) in;
    inPtr1 = (__m256d*) in + 1;
    inPtr2 = (__m256d*) in + 2;
    inPtr3 = (__m256d*) in + 3;

    const __m256d ones = reluGlobalOneVectorAVX;
    const __m256i bitmask = reluGlobalBitmask;

    for (int i = 0; i < unrolled ; ++i) {
        __m256i mask = _mm256_andnot_si256(*(__m256i*)inPtr, bitmask);
        __m256i mask1 = _mm256_andnot_si256(*(__m256i*)inPtr1, bitmask);
        __m256i mask2 = _mm256_andnot_si256(*(__m256i*)inPtr2, bitmask);
        __m256i mask3 = _mm256_andnot_si256(*(__m256i*)inPtr3, bitmask);

        *delOutPtr = _mm256_maskload_pd((double*)&ones, mask);
        *delOutPtr1 = _mm256_maskload_pd((double*)&ones, mask1);
        *delOutPtr2 = _mm256_maskload_pd((double*)&ones, mask2);
        *delOutPtr3 = _mm256_maskload_pd((double*)&ones, mask3);

        delOutPtr += 4;
        delOutPtr1 += 4;
        delOutPtr2 += 4;
        delOutPtr3 += 4;
    }

    double* inD = (double*)inPtr;
    double* actOutD = (double*)actOutPtr;
    double* delOutD = (double*)delOutPtr;
    for (int i = inD - in; i < args; ++i, ++inD, ++actOutD, ++delOutD) {
        if ((*((long long*)inD)) & (*((long long*)&bitmask))) {
            *actOutD = 0.0;
            *delOutD = 0.0;
        }
        else {
            *actOutD = *inD;
            *delOutD = 1.0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Intel C++ compiler supports x64 inline assembly if you can get your hands on it

Comment: MSVC is forgiving of type-based aliasing, like `gcc -fno-strict-aliasing`.  That may make it more conservative when optimizing.  Can you use `__restrict` to tell it about non-overlapping arrays?  Also, you don't need four different pointer variables, just use `delOutPtr[0] = ...;` and `delOutPtr[1] = ...` / ... / `delOutPtr+=4`.  Using more pointers is just tempting the compiler into running out of integer registers / doing more work instead of using small offsets in addressing modes.

Comment: Same for `inPtr1..3`, except I think you forgot to increment the input pointers inside the loop.  (Which might be making your code look faster than it is, if you don't actually read most of your input array.)

Comment: @PeterCordes in all my other versions of the function I've done it correct but you're right im so stupid - when I split up the loop i must have forgotten to copy/paste that bit! Thank you for pointing that out

Comment: @PeterCordes your previous answer sounded very informative but I am afraid I don't understand what you mean by it :) 
What is the purpose of __restrict and how does it help me?
And although I think I know what you mean by type-based aliasing I don't see how that affects performance..?

Comment: Which variables are you talking about exactly that are getting reloaded?  Is it only the `ones` you're using with `_mm256_maskload_pd`?  `maskload` doesn't have a register source form so there's no way for the compiler to optimize it into a register.  Perhaps you want `_mm256_cmp_epi64` or something to compute a mask instead of zero-mask loading one.

Comment: So the ones, zeros, and the bitmask vector - they all would benefit from being in registers (I would assume) as they're being usedin the main body of the loop - yet the disassembly shows them to be all stored on the stack and temporarily reloaded with ymmword ptr[rbp + n]. That's an interesting point about maskload though - I had no idea some assembly instructions could take memory locations only! As for using alternative cmp instructions, because maskload automatically zeroes out the destination, there's no need for a comparison, and I felt that fewer instructions are faster (?)

Comment: Re: `__restrict`: if the compiler thinks a store might modify some other variable, it has to reload that other variable every time.  Although `__m256d*` is a may-alias type like `char*` so it's not really possible for the compiler to assume that an assignment to a `__m256d*` doesn't modify things just based on type; it has to prove that based on it being a local var and a pointer to it not having escaped the function, so `delOutPtr` can't be pointing to `ones`.

Comment: @PeterCordes  So how may I make it entirely local then..? Or is this not possible :/ (Very grateful for a sudden wealth of assembly/low-level knowledge that the internet normally would never have taught me!)

Comment: It already is entirely local, it should be fine.  You haven't shown any asm output in the question, or a https://godbolt.org/ permalink, so the only problem I see is using 4 separate pointer variables instead of offsetting one in the loop which makes me worry about register allocation for lots of integer registers (and wasted loop overhead).  Also don't use `_mm256_maskload_pd` on a constant vector if you want the compiler to use registers; [`vmaskmovpd` doesn't have a reg,reg form](https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/vmaskmov).

Comment: @PeterCordes that's an interesting idea about the reg, reg form - so you think using multiple instructions to decisively load either the input or the zeros would end up being faster than using a single instruction that zeroes out the destination automatically, due to the alternative multiple instructions being able to utilise registers?

Comment: What?  No.  I think using `vpcmpeqq` or `vpcmpgtq` *instead of* maskload to compute purely in registers might be more efficient, and still doable one instruction.  Or do you want `1.0` not an all-ones bit pattern? At worst a `vblendvpd` to select based on the mask bit.

Comment: @PeterCordes Ok thank you for all your information and help! Hopefully I can fix this, and when I do I'll edit the code shown here to provide the final, (hopefully) most efficient code!

Comment: What the heck is `reluGlobalZeroVectorAVX` for?  If you have global variables for your vector constants, that would explain a lot of badness.  Use `const __m256d ones = _mm256_set1_pd(1.0);` as a local like a normal person and let the compiler put vector constants somewhere for you.  Never use `const __m256d global_var = ...;` at global scope.  Compilers are worse at it than you'd expect.  And especially not for an all-zero vector: compilers can zero a register on the fly with one very cheap instruction like `vxorpd xmm0, xmm0, xmm0`; you don't want a load.

Comment: @PeterCordes it was only becaause I read that static const lookup tables can be more efficient... but I’ve tested it and it does admittedly have absolutely no effect

Comment: I highly doubt that separating the loops is actually good.  Maybe some other missed-optimization was making the combined way look bad, like maybe having too many pointer variables instead of offsetting them.

Comment: @PeterCordes I’ll keep testing :) thank you